# Imported deno thirdparties in production

Tags: deno

Deno does not use any package manager like npm, it only imports the thirdparty dependencies with a URL. Lets see an example below:

`import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/abc@v1.0.0-rc8/mod.ts";`

Does the deployed code in production contain the content of `https://deno.land/x/abc@v1.0.0-rc8/mod.ts` or the server in production has to send a request to the URL to get the thirdparty code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For production, `deno` recommends saving your dependencies to `git`, if you follow that recommendation, then your server won't need to download anything since it will already be cached.

In order to do that you have to set the environment variable `DENO_DIR` to specify where do you want to download dependencies.

```
DENO_DIR=$PWD/vendor deno cache server.ts
# DENO_DIR=$PWD/vendor deno run server.ts
```

With the above command, all dependencies for `server.ts` will be downloaded into your project, inside `vendor/` directory, which you can commit to git.

Then on the production server, you'll have to set `DENO_DIR` to read from `vendor/` and not for the default path, which can be obtained by issuing:

```
deno info
```

---

If you don't store the dependencies on your version control system, then `deno` will download the dependencies once, and store them into `DENO_DIR` directory.

---

Taken from `deno` [manual](https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code#but-what-if-the-host-of-the-url-goes-down-the-source-wont-be-available):

### But what if the host of the URL goes down? The source won't be available.

> This, like the above, is a problem faced by any remote dependency
>   system. Relying on external servers is convenient for development but
>   brittle in production. Production software should always vendor its
>   dependencies. In Node this is done by checking node_modules into
>   source control. In Deno this is done by pointing $DENO_DIR to some
>   project-local directory at runtime, and similarly checking that into
>   source control:

```
# Download the dependencies.
DENO_DIR=./deno_dir deno cache src/deps.ts

# Make sure the variable is set for any command which invokes the cache.
DENO_DIR=./deno_dir deno test src

# Check the directory into source control.
git add -u deno_dir
git commit
```